# Playing MP3 with MediaResponse seems to be broken

Tags: actions-on-google, google-home

Something seems to have broken when it comes to playing MP3 files and live streams using MediaResponse on Google Home.

Without releasing any new version or changing stream URLs, playback simply no longer work in our app (on a Google Home Mini - still works in Simulator though), and I notice the same problem in other similar apps. Playing radio from TuneIn still works.

Anyone else with this problem?

Comment: Can you update the question to clarify what you mean by "no longer works"? I have seen some issues, but not a total failure, and the action I typically test ("talk to endless hold") with is working ok. Is it working on mobile or other devices besides the Mini?

Comment: Can you also post a minimal example that doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar issue with our Google Assistant application when providing a mp3 livestream using MediaResponse.

We previously ended the conversation like this

```
conv.close(new MediaObject({
    name: "Name",
    url: "https://url.to.livestream",
    description: "Description",
    image: new Image({
        url: "https://url.to.image"
    })
}));
```

What worked for us was to instead send the `MediaObject` using `conv.ask()`

```
conv.ask(new MediaObject({
    ...
}));
conv.ask(new Suggestions(["suggestion 1", "suggestion 2"]));
```

What is important here is to follow the `MediaResponse` with a `Suggestions` response since the app will fail otherwise.

> "Your Action must include suggestion chips if the response is not a
>   final response." https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses#media_responses

Maybe this will solve your issue as well?